# Reading a custom data type with error Prelude.read: no parse

Tags: parsing, haskell, functional-programming, typeclass

I am extremely new to functional programming and I have few custom data types of the following to represent a deck of cards.

**Data type for Suit**

```
data Suit = Spade | Club | Diamond | Heart
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum, Bounded)

instance Show Suit where
  show Spade = "S"
  show Club = "C"
  show Diamond = "D"
  show Heart = "H"

instance Read Suit where
  readsPrec _ [] = []
  readsPrec _ (s: str) = case s of
    'S' -> [(Spade, str)]
    'C' -> [(Club, str)]
    'D' -> [(Diamond, str)]
    'H' -> [(Heart, str)]
    _ -> []
```

**Data type for Rank**

```
data Rank = Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven | Eight | Nine | Ten
          | Jack | Queen | King | Ace
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum, Bounded)

instance Show Rank where
  show Ace = "A"
  show King = "K"
  show Queen = "Q"
  show Jack = "J"
  show rank = show $ fromEnum rank + 2

instance Read Rank where
  readsPrec _ [] = []
  readsPrec _ (s: str) = case s of
      'A' -> [(Ace, str)]
      'K' -> [(King, str)]
      'Q' -> [(Queen, str)]
      'J' -> [(Jack, str)]
      _   -> readNum
    where
      readNum
        | s >= '2' && s <= '9' = [(toEnum (ord s - ord '2') :: Rank, str)]
        | s == '1' = readZero str -- Read a following 0
        | otherwise = []
      readZero ('0': rest) = [(Ten, rest)]
      readZero _ = []
```

**Data type for Card**

```
data Card = Card Suit Rank
  deriving (Eq)

instance Show Card where
  show (Card suit rank) = show suit ++ show rank

instance Read Card where
  readsPrec _ str = do
     (s, rest) <- reads str
     (r, end) <- reads rest
     return (Card s r, end)
```

When I typed `read "S3H5" :: Card` in my stack ghci console, it shows an exception error of `*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse`.

**May I ask how to fix this?**

I have a string of Card information, for instance, "S3HA" which represents two Cards:

- Spade Three
- Heart Ace

What I am trying to achieve:

When I read the string of "S3HA", I want the output to be an array of

`[Card Spade Three, Card Heart Ace]`

**Please advise! I am relatively new to Haskell functional programming!**

And I do not want to modify the source code for the custom data type of `Card`, `Suit` and `Rank` above but utilizing those data types to create an array of `[Card]`. Could anyone provide ways to parse a string into a `[Card]`?

Comment: `read "S3" :: Card` works fine. The problem is that you can't say `read "S3H5" :: [Card]` because the list instance for `Read` assumes the string contains an actual list literal, not just juxtaposed strings for the type `a` of the list you want to read.

Comment: Then how can I read such that I am able to produce the output ```[Card Spade Three, Card Heart Ace]```?

Comment: I think you could use the `FlexibleInstances` extension to define your own `[Card]` instance for `Read` (which would also have to use the state monad in some way to traverse the string; `(s, rest) <- reads str` is doing to try to create a card from *every* character in the string, not just read a single character from the string and move on). I would suggest, though, using a proper parsing library like `parsec` or one of its variants instead of `Read`.

Comment: I don't think I can do that given that my task requirement does not allow me to modify the source code (for the custom data type of ```Card```, ```Suit```, and ```Rank``` above, but only utilizing those data types to create the output an array of ```[Card]```. I am not sure how to achieve this output with parsing method (my knowledge on haskell and parsing is very shallow), could you provide an example on how to parse an output of ```[Card]```? Thanks.

Comment: For lists, I think you need to redefine the `readList` method in your `Read Card` instance. If you do that then the predefined `instance Read a => Read [a]` will automagically call your own `readList`, and everything should work. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:readList

Answer (score 0):

As @chi says in the comments to the question, the most straightforward way to achieve your aim is to define the `readList` method for `Card`.

> For lists, I think you need to redefine the `readList` method in your `Read Card` instance. If you do that then the predefined instance `Read a => Read [a]` will automagically call your own `readList`, and everything should work.

One possible definition:

```
instance Read Card where
  ...

  readList str = do
      (card, rest) <- reads str
      if null rest then return ([card], "")
          else fmap (Data.Bifunctor.bimap (card:) id) (readList rest
```

Or maybe:

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP

...

instance Read Card where
  ...

  readList = readP_to_S (many (readS_to_P reads))
```

However, note also that a default `Show` and `Read` instance has some advantages:

- It is usual — that is, people will know what to expect. With a custom instance, it is necessary to inspect the instance definition in order to use it correctly, while a default instance can be used immediately and effortlessly *(except for a lot of typing)*.
- It is automatically generated — so it is unlikely there to be errors. It gives you a solid ground to stand on, for free, while a custom definition needs to be thoroughly checked if you want to ship the code in good faith.

Therefore, it may be more reasonable to put the same code into monomorphic functions, like say `parseCard`, `parseCards`, `renderCard` and `renderCards`, and have the best of both worlds.

Actually, I think custom `Read` instances are an obscure corner of Haskell. When I was researching for a similar problem a while ago, I could not find any guides on this subject. *(Compare with the abundance of guides on, say, cellular automata or free monads.)* This is maybe because people mostly live with the default derived instances until they really need to parse a lot of data, which is when advanced parsing libraries, such as `parsec`, come into play.